# Selenium - Chrome unexpected alert open

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Running the following code with headless Selenium I keep getting:

```
while True:
time.sleep(5)
try:
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="send"]'))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I tried to debug this screenshotting headless Selenium but I can't see any alerts at all.

I keep getting:

> Alert Text: {Alert text : Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }

Answer (score 0):

The below line instructs the browser to display an alert because of which you are getting 'Unexpected alert' exception.

```
 driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
```

It is not possible to take the screenshot from selenium while the alert is displayed in the browser, you will get exception. Still if you want to handle the alert exception remove above line of code and call below method code as below:
def handle_alert():
try:
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
print("Alert accepted")
except:
print("no Alert found")

Comment: So I should not use this line? The problem is that I need to suppress the warning if it appears.

Comment: Also deleting this line I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle alert first. And then do your click.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())  # this will wait 5 seconds for alert to appear
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert  # or self.driver.switch_to_alert() depends on your selenium version
    alert.accept()
except TimeoutException:
    pass
WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="send"]'))).click()
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure that the alert will come.  During the loop it can occurs in the second iteration or in the third or whatever, I'm not sure when

Comment: You can add a check for TimeoutException for WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present()). Wrap the logic of work with alert in try except block. In case there is no alert WebDriverWait will return TimeoutException. Catch it and move on

Comment: Tried your code, I have the same problem